# Why is it impossible to change the inode count of an ext filesystem?

Tags: ext4, ext3, inode

I know that it isn't possible to change the inode count of an ext filesystem after its creation, but I haven't been able to find any explanation on *why* it isn't.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: To change the inode count you need to either change the block size or the filesystem size.  That means reformatting.

Comment: @casey So growing the filesystem (provided there's space on the partition) would linearly increase the number of inodes?

Comment: [Yes](https://dpaste.de/4Pde)

Comment: @n.st yes, using `resize2fs` would have that effect.

Comment: Shrinking does not decrease, however.

Comment: Note also that resizing preserves the `bytes-per-inode` ratio. (cf. `man 8 mke2fs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because no one has written a tool that does it. And that's probably because it's a not entirely trivial change to the filesystem metadata.

There are other issues like this; for example you can't resize ext4 to >16TB. That needs 64bit structures which aren't used by default.

Same with other filesystems, for example you can't shrink XFS.

None of these things are impossible, but it seems that no tools exist to do it either, at least not directly. Someone would have to develop them... and that usually requires in depth knowledge of the specific filesystem.

Comment: I'm surprised that noone has written a tool to do that — given how many questions I've found about increasing the number of inodes, it would definitely be worthwhile.